# R: Creating Grid and checking what row falls into each cell with for loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, latitude-longitude

I have looked through many forum posts and have not found an answer. I have a large list of latitudes and longitudes and would like to make a grid of them and based on that grid have each pair of lat/longs be assigned a cell reference from that grid. Eventually I want to assign values based on the cell reference.  E.g. Lat `39.5645` and long `-122.4654` fall into grid cell reference 1, the total number of murders in that cell are 16 and assaults are 21. There is a better way to do this but this is the only way I know of.

```
#number of segments, this determines size of grid
segments <- 5
#use these to dvide up the arrays
Xcounter <-(max(cleantrain$X)-min(cleantrain$X))/segments
Ycounter <-(quantile (cleantrain$Y,.9999)-min(cleantrain$Y))/segments

#arrays created from the counter and lat and longs
Xarray <- as.data.frame(seq(from=min(cleantrain$X), to=max(cleantrain$X), by=Xcounter))
Yarray <-as.data.frame(seq(from=min(cleantrain$Y), to=quantile(cleantrain$Y,.9999), by=Ycounter))

#the max for the latitude is 90 but the .9999 percentile is ~39,
# but I still want the grid to include the 90
Yarray[6,1]<-max(cleantrain$Y)
#create dummy column so I know what the values shouldn't be when I print the results
cleantrain$Area <- seq(from =1, to=nrow(cleantrain), by =1)
#for loop that goes through once for each row in my data
for (k in 1:100) {
  #this loop goes through the longitudes 
  for (i in 1:seg-1) {
    #this loop goes though the latitudes 
    for (j in 1:seg-1){
      #should check if the row fits into that grid 
      if(cleantrain$Y[k] < Yarray[(j+1),1] && 
          cleantrain$X[k] < Xarray[(i+1),1] &&
          cleantrain$Y[k] >= Yarray[j,1] &&
           cleantrain$X[k] >= Xarray[i,1]){
        #writes to the row the cell reference
        cleantrain$Area[k] <- ((i-1)*segments+j)
      } 
    }
  }
}
#check the results
cleantrain$Area[1:100]
```

if you only write the i value to `cleantrain$Area` it will always print 1 instead of 1-5. But the j for loop will print 1-5 like it is supposed to. But if you went into the if statement and switched the i and j loop references, the j would always be 1 and the i would always be 1-5.

Here are my array values

```
#Yarray
    1                                                                          37.70788
    2                                                                          37.73030
    3                                                                          37.75272
    4                                                                          37.77514
    5                                                                          37.79756
    6                                                                          37.81998
#Xarray
1                                                            -122.5136
2                                                            -122.1109
3                                                            -121.7082
4                                                            -121.3055
5                                                            -120.9027
6                                                            -120.5000
```

**EDIT:**

Here are the first 10 lats and longs:

```
 cleantrain$Y[1:10]
 [1] 37.77460 37.77460 37.80041 37.80087 37.77154 37.71343 37.72514 37.72756 37.77660 37.80780
cleantrain$X[1:10]
 [1] -122.4259 -122.4259 -122.4244 -122.4270 -122.4387 -122.4033 -122.4233 -122.3713 -122.5082 -122.4191
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702437/in-r-how-to-average-spatial-points-data-over-spatial-grid-squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above isn't reproducible, but I think I get the gist of what you're trying to achieve. In this example, I will assume I have a bunch of `x` coordinates and `y` coordinates which are randomly generated. `x` in `[0,1]` and y in `[10, 20]`.

```
df <- data.frame(xcoord = runif(1000), ycoord = runif(1000, min=10, max=20))
```

To solve the problem of assigning points to a grid we simply need to map the points to some defined portions. The easiest way to do this is via the `cut` function. For example to map the `xcoord` to a bunch of numbers of length 10 and `ycoord` to a bunch of numbers of length 9, we would do:

```
df$x_cut <- as.numeric(cut(df$xcoord, 10))
df$y_cut <- as.numeric(cut(df$ycoord, 9))
```

If you want to cut things in a specific interval, you could do it like this: `cut(runif(10), c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1))`, and see [this answer for other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r).

Now we basically have our grid. If you want to map it to the individual numbers we can create such a mapping.

```
grid_index <- expand.grid(x_cut=1:xlength, y_cut=1:ylength)
grid_index$index <- row.names(grid_index)
```

and merge the two data frames to get the whole picture.

```
df_all <- merge(df, grid_index)
```

---

Full code:

```
df <- data.frame(xcoord = runif(1000), ycoord = runif(1000, min=10, max=20))

df$x_cut <- as.numeric(cut(df$xcoord, 10))
df$y_cut <- as.numeric(cut(df$ycoord, 9))

grid_index <- expand.grid(x_cut=1:xlength, y_cut=1:ylength)
grid_index$index <- row.names(grid_index)

df_all <- merge(df, grid_index)
```