# R - Place Longitude and Latitude coordinates into a 2x2 grid

Tags: r, geospatial

I have a dataframe with Longitudes and Latitudes and I would like to create a 0.5x0.5 degrees grid that shows which lat, long fall within it. So far, I have tried several solutions, including some found here on stackoverflow, that use `cut` and `expand.grid` as well as code that uses the package "sp" but none has worked out for me (maybe I simply can't implement them).

Any suggestions on how I can group my data into a 0.5x0.5 degrees grids?

| Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- |
| 31.602 | -39.848 |
| 31.675 | -39.467 |
| 31.747 | -39.083 |
| 32.152 | -36.795 |
| 32.218 | -36.408 |
| 32.285 | -36.022 |
| 32.348 | -35.635 |
| 32.412 | -35.247 |
| 32.475 | -34.858 |
| 32.535 | -34.47 |
| 32.595 | -34.082 |
| 32.677 | -33.707 |
| 32.763 | -33.323 |

Thank you all for your time and effort.

Edit: My best effort was this snippet

```
library(tidyverse)

pos <- dassem %>% 
  dplyr::select(Latitude, Longitude)

gridx <- seq(from = min(dassem$Longitude), to = max(dassem$Longitude), by = 2)
gridy <- seq(from = min(dassem$Latitude), to = max(dassem$Latitude), by = 2)

xcell <- unlist(lapply(pos$Longitude,function(x) min(which(gridx>x))))
ycell <- unlist(lapply(pos$Latitude,function(y) min(which(gridy>y))))

pos$cell <- (length(gridx) - 1) * ycell + xcell

pos

# A tibble: 45,647 x 3
   Latitude Longitude  cell
      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1     51.7     -54.9   638
 2     51.9     -54.5   638
 3     52.1     -54.1   638
 4     52.3     -53.7   639
 5     52.5     -53.2   639
 6     52.7     -52.8   639
 7     52.9     -52.4   639
 8     53.2     -52.0   639
```

which, as you can see, does not return a 2x2 degrees grid (I set it to 2x2, and not 0.5x0.5).

Comment: can you show us the code of your best shot?

Comment: Adjusted the OP to your question

Comment: Okay, I think this is a bit clearer; but I'm unsure what this grid looks like to you. I suspect you're trying to hold a data structure in `cell` that a tibble is not meant to hold and that your operations above do not yield. Can you give us an idea of what this "grid" looks like to you? is it a four point polygon per row?

Comment: Otherwise, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484381/r-divide-latitude-and-longitude-into-grid-sections?rq=1) should do the trick?

Comment: For example, looking at the 1st row, the coordinates 31.602, - 39.848 would from one of the vertices of a 0.5x0.5 square. The coordinates (31.602 + 0.5, -39.848), (31.602+0.5, -39.848 + 0.5), and (31.602, -39.848 + 0.5) would form the other 3 vertices of the square grid. Now, I would like R to show which coordinates (rows) fall within the square I have formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfectly clear what your expected output is, but I'll give a few options:

```r
dassem <- structure(list(Latitude = c(31.602, 31.675, 31.747, 32.152, 32.218, 32.285, 32.348, 32.412, 32.475, 32.535, 32.595, 32.677, 32.763), Longitude = c(-39.848, -39.467, -39.083, -36.795, -36.408, -36.022, -35.635, -35.247, -34.858, -34.47, -34.082, -33.707, -33.323)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

I'll start with a 1-degree grid (arbitrary):

```r
degx <- degy <- 1 # grid sizes
gridx <- seq(min(dassem$Longitude), max(dassem$Longitude) + degx, by = degx)
gridy <- seq(min(dassem$Latitude), max(dassem$Latitude) + degy, by = degy)

dassem %>%
  mutate(
    x = findInterval(Longitude, gridx),
    y = findInterval(Latitude, gridy)
  )
#    Latitude Longitude x y
# 1    31.602   -39.848 1 1
# 2    31.675   -39.467 1 1
# 3    31.747   -39.083 1 1
# 4    32.152   -36.795 4 1
# 5    32.218   -36.408 4 1
# 6    32.285   -36.022 4 1
# 7    32.348   -35.635 5 1
# 8    32.412   -35.247 5 1
# 9    32.475   -34.858 5 1
# 10   32.535   -34.470 6 1
# 11   32.595   -34.082 6 1
# 12   32.677   -33.707 7 2
# 13   32.763   -33.323 7 2
```

This provides the grid indices for each point, if that's of any interest.

[image]

If you don't need the individual indices, you can combine them (as I did for that image):

```r
dassem %>%
  mutate(
    cell = paste(findInterval(Longitude, gridx),
                 findInterval(Latitude, gridy),
                 sep = ",")
  )
#    Latitude Longitude cell
# 1    31.602   -39.848  1,1
# 2    31.675   -39.467  1,1
# 3    31.747   -39.083  1,1
# 4    32.152   -36.795  4,1
# 5    32.218   -36.408  4,1
# 6    32.285   -36.022  4,1
# 7    32.348   -35.635  5,1
# 8    32.412   -35.247  5,1
# 9    32.475   -34.858  5,1
# 10   32.535   -34.470  6,1
# 11   32.595   -34.082  6,1
# 12   32.677   -33.707  7,2
# 13   32.763   -33.323  7,2
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. Thank you very much. Also, another big thanks to everyone who has tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

df_sf <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

grid <- df_sf %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  st_make_grid(cellsize = 0.5)

df %>%
  mutate(polygon_id = st_intersects(df_sf, grid) %>% map_int(1))
```